# Teradata SQL Update Table "Query Error 3802 Database 'oo' does not exist"

Tags: sql, sql-update, teradata

I need help with the following query code. Currently it is giving me the 3802 query error "Database does not exist". Well I did my "from" selection query as 'oo', so that definitely exists. This worked yesterday with some minor changes to the "from" part of the query. The assistance is appreciated.

---

```
UPDATE snd_bqa.open_order_all_test
FROM (
SELECT 
CASE WHEN m.order_status_desc = 'Completed' AND NVL(c.supptype, 'NULL') <> 'CAN'
        THEN 'YES'
        ELSE 'NO'
        END AS "Order Complete",
CASE WHEN m.order_status_desc = 'Completed' AND c.supptype = 'CAN'
        THEN 'YES'
        ELSE 'NO'
        END AS "Order Cancelled",
CASE WHEN pih.effective_start_date IS NOT NULL AND pih.product_instance_status_code = 3
        THEN 'YES'
        ELSE 'NO'
        END AS "Service Active in PB",
c.ordernumber,
c1.order_requested_due_date,
c.creationdate AS "Order Creation Date",
c.ordersubmitdate AS "Order Submit Date",
c.lastupdateddate,
c.supptype,
m.order_status_desc,
m.phase_stage,
cus.sub_nasp_id,
cus.gch_id,
b.work_order_no,
b.itemcode,
b.instance_id,
COALESCE(b.specific_date, b.standard_date) AS "Service Req Due Date",
m.milestone,
m.milestone_desc,
cus.custlegalname,
a.account_number,
vle.vle_id,
vle.currency_cd,
cus.duns_number,
a.cle_vle_id,
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(2) AS "Originally Loaded",
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(2) AS "Last Upd",
CAST((CASE WHEN m.order_status_desc = 'Completed' AND NVL(c.supptype, 'NULL') <> 'CAN'
        THEN c.lastupdateddate
        ELSE NULL
        END) AS TIMESTAMP(2)) "Order Completed Date",
CAST((CASE WHEN m.order_status_desc = 'Completed' AND c.supptype = 'CAN'
        THEN c.lastupdateddate
        ELSE NULL
        end) AS TIMESTAMP(2)) "Order Cancelled Date",
pih.last_modified AS "Service Last Modified Date",
pih.effective_start_date AS "Service Effective Date"


FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM edw_stg_ord_cw_vw.cwpc_basketitem
    WHERE itemcode LIKE 'PR%'
    AND (instance_id, lastupdateddate) IN (
            SELECT instance_id, MAX(lastupdateddate)
            FROM edw_stg_ord_cw_vw.cwpc_basketitem
            GROUP BY instance_id
            )) AS b
INNER JOIN edw_stg_ord_cw_vw.cworderinstance AS c
    ON c.basket_id = b.basketid
    AND c.isactive = 1
    AND c.request_type = 'ORD'
LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT c.ordernumber, 
        MAX(COALESCE(b.specific_date, b.standard_date)) order_requested_due_date
        FROM edw_stg_ord_cw_vw.cworderinstance AS c
        INNER JOIN edw_stg_ord_cw_vw.cwpc_basketitem AS b
            ON b.basketid = c.basket_id

            AND c.request_type = 'ORD'
            AND c.isactive = 1
        GROUP BY c.ordernumber
        ) AS c1
    ON c1.ordernumber = c.ordernumber
LEFT JOIN edw_stg_ord_cw_vw.uno_customer AS cus
    ON cus.cworderid = c.cwdocid
    AND cus.oi_customer_id = c.ordering_customer_id
LEFT JOIN edw_stg_ord_cw_vw.uno_milestone AS m
    ON m.milestone_id = c.milestone_id
LEFT JOIN edw_stg_ord_cw_vw.uno_account AS a
    ON a.cworderid = c.cwdocid
    AND b.account_id = a.oi_account_id
LEFT JOIN edw_stg_ord_cw_vw.uno_cle_vle AS vle
    ON vle.cle_vle_id = a.cle_vle_id
    AND c.cwdocid = vle.cworderid
INNER JOIN snd_bqa.open_order_all_test tst
    ON tst."Service Instance ID" = b.instance_id
    AND tst."Milestone" <> m.milestone
LEFT JOIN edw_pb_stg_vw.product_instance_history AS pih
    ON pih.general_5 = tst."Service Instance ID"
WHERE cus.sub_nasp_id NOT IN ('19HNYO', '23MAXA', '19HNYR', '10INTD')
AND COALESCE(b.specific_date, b.standard_date, c1.order_requested_due_date) BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - 60 AND CURRENT_DATE - 30
)  oo

SET "Order Complete" = oo."Order Complete",
"Order Cancelled" = oo."Order Cancelled",
"Service Active in PB" = oo."Service Active in PB",
"Service Order Number" = oo.ordernumber,
"Order Requested Due Date" = oo.order_requested_due_date,
"Order Last Updated" = oo.lastupdateddate,
"Order Creation Date" = oo."Order Creation Date",
"Order Submit Date" = oo."Order Submit Date",
"Order Supp Type" = oo.c.supptype,
"Order Status" = oo.order_status_desc,
"Phase Stage" = oo.phase_stage,
"Milestone" = oo.milestone,
"Milestone Description" = oo.milestone_desc,
"NASP ID" = oo.sub_nasp_id,
"GCH ID" = oo.gch_id,
"Work Order Numbers" = oo.work_order_no,
"Product Code" = oo.itemcode,
"Service Requested Due Date" = oo."Service Req Due Date",
"Customer Name" = oo.custlegalname,
"Account Number" = oo.account_number,
"VLE ID" = oo.vle_id,
"Currency Code" = oo.currency_cd,
"DUNs Number" = oo.duns_number,
"CLE VLE ID" = oo.cle_vle_id,
"Last Record Update" = oo."Last Upd",
"Order Completed Date" = oo."Order Completed Date",
"Order Cancelled Date" = oo."Order Cancelled Date",
"Service Last Modified Date" = oo."Service Last Modified Date",
"Service Effective Date" = oo."Service Effective Date"


WHERE open_order_all_test."Service Instance ID" = oo.instance_id


;
```

Comment: UPDATE FROM (SELECT FROM (SELECT FROM)) oo <-|| should be here instead

Comment: No the 'oo' is in the right place, Teradata highlights my open and close parenthesis. Also, if I just took the FROM query and ran it by itself, it runs perfectly, so that's not the problem. For some reason it's not recognizing the 'oo' as an alias...

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I had oo.c.supptype, when it should have just been oo.supptype
This caused Teradata to think 'oo' was referring to a database. case closed.